# Insert/Read pdf file from MySQL Database through Python

Tags: python, mysql, blob

I am trying to create function that I can upload and download (or View) pdf file into my database with PyQt5. Basically, I want to achieve following steps

1. Click button to upload, then opens the window to select pdf file
2. From the Tablewidget or some other available views, make function to download PDF or view PDF file that is saved in my database through 'step 1)'

I think I figured one way to upload the file,

```py
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

def write_file(data, filename):
    # Convert binary data to proper format and write it on Hard Disk
    with open(filename, 'wb', encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as file:

        file.write(data)

def readBLOB(emp_id, photo, bioData):
    print("Reading BLOB data from python_Employee table")

    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host="00.00.00.000",
                                             user="user",
                                             password="pswd",
                                             database="database")

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        sql_fetch_blob_query = """SELECT * from python_Employee where id = %s"""

        cursor.execute(sql_fetch_blob_query, (emp_id,))
        record = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in record:
            print("Id = ", row[0], )
            print("Name = ", row[1])
            image = row[2]
            file = row[3]
            print("Storing employee image and bio-data on disk \n")
            write_file(image, photo)
            write_file(file, bioData)

    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed to read BLOB data from MySQL table {}".format(error))

    finally:
        if (connection.is_connected()):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")

path1 = r'C:\Users\Bruce Ko\Desktop\Minsub Lee\Development\Git\Inventory Software\testdata.pdf'
path2 = r'C:\Users\Bruce Ko\Desktop\Minsub Lee\Development\Git\Inventory Software\eric_bioData.txt'

readBLOB(1, path1, path2)
```

From above programming, I could see from *MySQL Workbench* that my pdf file is uploaded (Even if I cannot read from there. Only binary information was available while uploaded image file was readable as image)

So if above function is correct to upload the pdf file, how can I download or read it? Above code is from https://pynative.com/python-mysql-blob-insert-retrieve-file-image-as-a-blob-in-mysql/ and reading blob part from above link does not work out for me. it leaves me error like following

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

I would much appreciated any help on this!

Comment: Inserting and reading from the DB (be it an image, pdf or whatever) is not doing it with Qt so pyqt5 is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. However, I was wondering whether it is possible to make downloadable link on Tablewidget when I enumerate my database on it.